# How can I query the data stored in Azure Table Storage using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, storage

We will be writing several hundred thousand rows of data to an Azure Table Storage Container. The data is made up of 4 columns, 1 of which contains a lot of JSON text which is the main column I'm interested in.

How can I query this data using T-SQL? I was hoping to join this with some existing data we currently hold in a table on SQL Server too.

I am new to Azure Storage and am trying to work out if I have to query the data directly or can I get it to my SQL Server to perform some more detailed querying? It is being stored on Azure to start with due to ease and cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Table storage does not support SQL: https://db-engines.com/en/system/Microsoft+Azure+Table+Storage%3BMicrosoft+SQL+Server

If your store your data on blob storage you might be able to use Polybase to query data from your SQL Server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks for that info. Is there a way I can move this data from the Azure Table to a SQL Sever Database and/or somewhere I could query it with TSQL?

Comment: sure, for example by using Azure Data Factory and copy from Table to SQL DB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage